# Generate Poisson Confidence Limit using R

Tags: r, poisson

I have use the reference from [here](http://www.nbdpn.org/docs/Ch_8_Statistics6-04.pdf) (Page 19 of the PDF) to calculate the confidence interval of a direct standardized incidence rate. The chapter quoted `Table of 95% Confidence Limits for the Number of Cases, for 1-29 Cases, Based on the Poisson Distribution`, which is attached here:

[image]

I tried to generate the number using `ci.poisson` function in `epicalc` package:

```
> ci.poisson(0,29)
 events person.time incidence se exact.lower95ci exact.upper95ci
      0          29         0  0               0       0.1272069
```

The output is different from the PDF's table, which should be `0.0000`-`3.6889`. I wonder if I am using the wrong function for generating the numbers. How can I construct that table using R? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can reproduce the results from the table using `ci.poisson(n, 1)`, where `n` is the number of cases. But you could also calculate the [confidence limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval) yourself.

Comment: Oops, forgot that you're looking at standardized rates. I'd suggest that you consider sending this over to CrossValidated.

Comment: The equations in your referenced text are pretty straightforward.  Why not just roll your own function?